# Story about separate individuals coming together to make some supernatural universe power

Tags: story-identification

A long time ago when I was a kid, I was really into fantasy books and went through them left and right. For some reason there is this one story that I can only remember a single detail about that keeps popping up and I really would like to find out what it is and re-read it!

I am trying to piece some of the details and I know it's not much to go on, but basically the fact I remember **was that these three(maybe more or less) people with no relation were given powers and when they all came together the power merged and gave them the ability to create and destroy the entire universe.**

I think the story was basically told from 3 separate perspectives (of the different individuals) and were completely different, but at the end somehow they all tied together and when they merged/met they thought as one individual and was granted some insane universe creating power.

I know this isn't much to go on but does anyone have any remote idea what I am talking about?

EDIT: So to add a few more details, I read this around 8-10 years ago, so the oldest I could've been when I read this was 13ish. So 2011 and earlier?

I also don't believe it was a series, I remember it as being a single novel.

I think the weapon had a really foreign unique name when the three people were merged together, a proper name with capital letter. (I think it had a hyphen in it)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a pretty good start, but there are probably still a few details you can [edit] into your question.  For example, approximately what years would this be?  We don't know when you were a kid.  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) in case they help you recall anything else.

Comment: There's also _Arc of the Dream_ by A.A. Attanasio.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like [The Gods Themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gods_Themselves) by Asimov. There is a parallel universe, where the inhabitants live in triplets, which merge to form a single being.

Comment: That was my first thought but Estwald doesn't have any special power to create universes or otherwise.

Comment: True, but the question is very fuzzy about the details.  So I thought, what the heck... :)

Comment: Seems like a good story but this one isn't it. The three people who merged were a one off thing, it wasn't applicable to inhabitants. I feel like I remember the stories happening on the same world (whether at the same time or in the future/past), but not in a parallel universe.

Comment: My first reaction, also.

Answer (score 4):

Although I think @Dima may be on to something, I'll give an alternative, the instances where several incarnations of Michael Moorcock's [Eternal Champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Champion_(character)) perform a mystical merger like this. Moorcock liked the device so much he used it twice.

In *[The Sailor on the Seas of Fate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sailor_on_the_Seas_of_Fate)*, [Elric of Melniboné](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elric_of_Melnibon%C3%A9), Prince [Corum Jhaelen Irsei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corum_Jhaelen_Irsei), [Dorian Hawkmoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorian_Hawkmoon), and [Erekosë](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erekos%C3%AB)

> join into the Four in One, a single cosmic being with four faces, to defeat the sorcerers Agak and Gagak who have assumed the forms of giant city-sized machines, in order to suck the Universe dry of energy. They use the scary power thus gained to restore swaths of the Universe destroyed by Agak and Gagak.

In *[The Vanishing Tower](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/60149.The_Vanishing_Tower)*, Elric, Corum, and Erekosë

> become the Three in One to defeat the tower's master  Voilodion Ghagnasdiak, and take McGuffins from the tower that are later fired like Chekhov's pistols.

Comment: Low-key didn't know the concept of merging into one "super" entity was more common then I thought hahaha! But I don't believe this is it, they all had their own stories and fights and at the end they almost ascended to become one and be the "power"

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be remembering different books in **Michael Moorcock's Eternal Champion** universe.

In one novel, "**The King of the Swords**", three aspects of the eternal champion, Elric, Corum and Erekosë, linked together to form "The Three Who Are One".

In another novel, "**The Quest for Tanelorn**", the three are joined by Hawkmoon to form "The Four Who Are One", a being that had "insane universe creating power". That story is told from Hawkmoon's perspective. In the Elric novel "**The Sailor on the Seas of Fate**", we see the same story from Elric's view.

Comment: Took a look through those books, I like the plotline so I might add that to my list in the future but that isn't it. I feel like the story included a modern element to it and those names don't ring a bell. I also know for sure it was either 3 or 4. It wasn't both even though it is in a different story